# trying to proof $f \in L_p, ||f||_r → ||f||_\infty$

Tags: measure-theory

I've found a solution in a book (image) but I don't get this step... maybe if f and g are non negative, is $\int f.g≤\int f\int g$ a property? I don't remember this really.
$0<p<\infty$
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr9jI.png

Comment: That step is simply Holder inequality $$\int fg \le ||f||_{\infty} \cdot ||g||_1$$

Comment: This is called "Holder inequality" (and it's not what you wrote. It's $$\int |fg|\leq \|f\|_{L^p}\|g\|_{L^q}$$ where $1/p+1/q=1$.

Comment: I forgot to say $0<p<\infty$ , Holder is only for p and q in (0,1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $A=\{ |f| > \|f\|_{\infty}\}$ has measure zero so when integrating over space $X$, it suffices to integrate over $A^c$. On this space, we know $|f|\le \|f\|_{\infty}$ which you apply to the $|f|^{r-p}$ term.

Comment: Thanks bro, I have another question in the next step book defines a set $B=\{ |f| > \|f\|_{\infty} - \epsilon \}$ and says B is non-locally null... could you tell me where that comes from?